# Problems finding links in the navigation bar in vue js whith router

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm-install, router

When I start my production server I get the following error:

The "_omappvp" cookie will soon be rejected because the "sameSite" attribute is set to "none" or an invalid value, without the "secure" attribute. For more information on the "sameSite" attribute, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Also I press the item in my About menu everything works but if I write in the address bar
www.miosito.it/about gives me error 404 page not found

The router configuration file is:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Admin from './views/Admin.vue'
import Notfound from "./components/404.vue";
import Overview from "./views/Overview.vue";
import Profile from "./views/Overview.vue";
import Products from "./views/Products.vue";
import  Orders from "./views/Overview.vue";

import  Preload from "./components/Preload2.vue";

//import  About from "./components/unity.vue";

//import Products from "./views/Products.vue";
import {fb} from './firebase'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes:
   [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },

  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'Notfound',
    component: Notfound
  },

  {
    path: '/preload',
    name: 'Preload',
    component: Preload
  },


  {
    path: '/admin',
    name: 'admin',
    component: Admin,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    children:[
      {
        path: "overview",
        name: "overview",
        component: Overview
      },

      {
        path: "Products",
        name: "Products",
        component: Products
      },

      {
        path: "profile",
        name: "profile",
        component: Profile
      },
   
      {
        path: "orders",
        name: "orders",
        component: Orders
      },

     
      
    ]


  },
 

  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
  },

  {
    path: '/lavori',
    name: 'Lavori',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/Lavori.vue')
  }
  

]


})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth)
  const currentUser = fb.auth().currentUser

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
      next('/')
  } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
      next()
  } else {
      next()
  }
})

export default router
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

in the navbar bootstrap I call the links in this way

```html
  <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/about" class="nav-link" href="#">About</router-link>
            </li>
```

My web space is on the following server "000webhost"

www.000webhost.com

What should I do to enable the ability to write address in the bar and resolve the error?
The localhost works everything and detects no errors.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The version of the packages I installed is the following:

```js
{
  "name": "vue-shop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babylonjs/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@babylonjs/loaders": "^4.1.0",
    "@hapi/cryptiles": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.13.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "node-ipc": "^9.1.1",
    "parse5": "^2.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "run": "^1.4.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-babylonjs": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "vue-fire": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-unity-webgl": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The version of the packages I installed is the following:

Do you know how the problem is solved?
Thanks so much